# How to undo click in android switches?

Tags: android, android-switch

In my android app, I have a switch widget, and I set a oncheckchange listener like this

```
            main.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                    if (no_internet()) {
                          // cancel click...
                          return; 
                    }
                    if (image.getApproved()) {
                        if (arg1) {
                            for(FishImage image : imagestoshow) {
                                image.setIsMain(false);
                            }
                        }
                        image.setIsMain(arg1);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Basically, I do something if there is internet, but if there isn't, then I want to cancel the change to the switch. Right now, it will change the state of the switch. If I try changing the state in the code, since this code occurs before android changes the state, it will have no effect.

I need a way cancel the switch, so if I do it, it should be as if I never clicked it.

Comment: Have you considered disabling the control instead?

Answer (score 5):

I would go with `setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)` instead and catch the `onClick(View)` callback. Then just `toggle()` the switch if you don't want to follow through with the click.

Don't use the `onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, boolean)` callback because you will end up with an infinite loop by calling `toggle()` inside.

**Example**

```
main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View clickedView) {
        // Cast to get access to Switch methods
        Switch switchView = (Switch) clickedView; 

        if (no_internet()) {
            switchView.toggle();
            return; 
        }
        if (image.getApproved()) {
            if (switchView.isChecked()) {
                for(FishImage image : imagestoshow) {
                    image.setIsMain(false);
                }
            }
            image.setIsMain(switchView.isChecked());
        }
    }
});
```